# angular JS use front end or backend API sorting

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ng-table. Sorting is already included.

What do you suggest. Use and let angular to sort and search or do a back end logic for that?

How big is my table: 1000 rows or less ...

Comment: If you always know the size of the data, test frontend only solution first to see if you got any performance issues, assuming angular-only will be more faster to implement and less complex. If this doesn't work you need it involve backend. :/